# Visual Studio Deployment Package - change the file structure the .zip creates?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-deployment-project, ajaxmin

Everything works as expected but I would like to improve the directory structure that the .zip produces.

When I create a deployment package I have it create in a custom directory which works fine but the .zip it creates is in the structure of:

```
content/c_c/users/pcName/documents/VS2010/Projects/ProjectName/obj/release/package/packageTmp
```

Only in the `packageTmp` directory do I get to the files I want!

Is there a way for the created zip to not include all of those empty directories?

Answer (score 1):

I never understood the folder structure either. By using msdeploy to publish the site it uses that folder structure to deploy multiple sites/assets at once. It's annoying when looking at the package itself but it does "work". Just use msdeploy to actually deploy the package and you don't have to look at the crazy folder structure. :)

Comment: +1 it's completely crazy.  Always get asked about it when people go poking in the zip files.

Comment: I am not quite sure if "Just use msdeploy and you don't have to see the mess" is an appropriate stance in development. I can't use msdeploy, for example, and still would enjoy if the files were 15 levels higher in the ZIP. So I suppose it all is just "impossible".